# Showing dynamic text in spinner angular material

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, spinner

I have a spinner , but I also want some text in the spinner independent of the component. So for example if you are doing a save action, then the spinner will showing: ...saving. But for example if you do a search action. The spinner will showing: ..processing and so on.

I have this as spinner component:

```
<div *ngIf="(isLoading | async)" class="overlay">
  <div>
    <mat-progress-spinner class="spinner" [color]="color" [mode]="mode" [value]="value"> </mat-progress-spinner>
    <div style="position:relative; top: -60px; left: 30px;">{{message}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and ts script:

```
export class LoaderComponent {
  color = 'primary';
  mode = 'indeterminate';
  value = 50;
  message = 'Hello there';
  isLoading: Subject<boolean> = this.loaderService.loaderState;
  constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) {}
}
```

and then for example I load the spinner in this component: listComponent

```
   <app-loader ></app-loader>
```

So I see the spinner but not the message.

So what I have to improve so that the text will also been shown?

And how to make the text dynamically? So that you can put any text message in it?

Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
<div *ngIf="(isLoading | async)" class="overlay">
  <div>
    <mat-progress-spinner class="spinner" [color]="color" [mode]="mode" [value]="value"> </mat-progress-spinner>
    <div style="position:absolute; top: -60px; left: 30px;">{{message}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
export class LoaderComponent {
  color = 'primary';
  mode = 'indeterminate';
  value = 50;
  @Input()
  message = 'Hello there';

  isLoading: Subject<boolean> = this.loaderService.loaderState;
  constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) {}
}
```

and this is the css:

```
.overlay {
  position:fixed;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:rgba(74,74,74,.8);
  z-index:99999;
}
 .spinner {
   margin:auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: "So I see the spinner but not the message" if you're not able to see hello there since that is the message property in your component.ts then you should first focus on the div styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find Working demo here in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dtmvs8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

You have to use `Behavior Subject` and `service`...

Your app.component.html is..

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">Spinner Demo</mat-toolbar>

<div style="margin:1em">  
    <button style="margin:1rem" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="spinner('search')">Search</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="spinner('Send')">Send</button>
    <button style="margin:1rem" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="spinner('Save')">Save</button>
</div>
     <app-search-output ></app-search-output>
```

Your app.component.ts is...

```
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor( private serachService: SearchService){
  }
  spinner(term){
    this.serachService.sendData(term);
  }
  ngOnInit(){
  } 
}
```

Your Service where you can use `behaviorSubject` as like this...

```
export class SearchService {
     searchData$: BehaviorSubject<object[]> = new BehaviorSubject<object[]>([{}]);
     constructor() { }
     sendData(term){
         this.searchData$.next(term)
     }
     getData(){
         return this.searchData$.asObservable();
     }
}
```

Your spinner component HTML is...

```
 <div style="margin:2em auto; padding:1rem; box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px red; width:50vw">
     <span style="margin:1em; padding:1rem">{{bookData$ |async |json}}</span>
     <mat-spinner style="margin:1em" color="warn" ></mat-spinner>
 </div>
```

Your spinner.component.ts is ...

```
export class SearchOutputComponent implements OnInit {
   bookData$;
   constructor(private searchService: SearchService) { }
   ngOnInit() {
        this.bookData$ = this.searchService.getData();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass text values as `@Input` to your component and use the component as below

I believe you are not able to see it because of css issue. Try making the text `position:absolute`.

```
<div *ngIf="(isLoading | async)" class="overlay">
  <div>
    <mat-progress-spinner class="spinner" [color]="color" [mode]="mode" [value]="value"> </mat-progress-spinner>
    <div style="position:absolute; top: -60px; left: 30px;">{{message}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To further debug please create a stackblitz.

`<app-loader [message] = "Processing"></app-loader>`

***Spinner Component***

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class LoaderComponent {
  color = 'primary';
  mode = 'indeterminate';
  value = 50;
  @Input()
  message = 'Hello there'; // Default text will be Hello there but if you pass anything as stated above then it will be replaced.
  isLoading: Subject<boolean> = this.loaderService.loaderState;
  constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I stil only see the spinner , no text. I made property: process = 'processing'; and in template:  <app-loader [message] = process ></app-loader>

Comment: Please create a stackblitz to debug further or you can open dev tools and inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change style position to relative in your html file it should work:

**HTML file**

```
    <div *ngIf="(isLoading | async)" class="overlay">
      <div>
        <mat-progress-spinner class="spinner" [color]="color" [mode]="mode" [value]="value"> </mat-progress-spinner>
        <div style="position:relative; top: -60px; left: 30px;">{{message}}
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**TS file**

```
export class ProgressSpinnerOverviewExample {
   color = 'primary';
  mode = 'indeterminate';
  value = 50;
  @Input()
  message = 'Hello';
  isLoading = true;
  constructor() {}
}
```